# How to pass custom arguments to dataTables footerCallback

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to add a custom argument to `footerCallback` in jQuery dataTables.

This is some part of my code :

```
oTableClient = $('#tbl_client').DataTable({
    "footerCallback": function(){
      dataTableFooterCallback('client');
     }
});
function dataTableFooterCallback(type, row, data, start, end, display) {
    var api = this.api(), data;

    if (type == 'client') {
        data = api.column(6, {page: 'current'}).data();
    } else {
        data = api.column(5, {page: 'current'}).data();
    }
}
```

But getting an error,

> TypeError: this.api is not a function
>   var api = this.api(), data;

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the dataTable API on `this` where it not exists. Every dataTable method or callback returns either an API or the API accessible through the `this` context, but you have to pass it yourself if you want to operate on `this.api()` in your own function. You can do that by calling the `dataTableFooterCallback()` with [**`apply()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) :

```js
footerCallback: function() {
  dataTableFooterCallback.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

Now you have passed `this` to `dataTableFooterCallback` and have access to the API :

```js
function dataTableFooterCallback(type, row, data, start, end, display) {
  //get first row trough the API
  console.log(this.api().row(0).data())
  //rest of passed arguments same as footerCallback()
  console.log(arguments)
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/95h3a8nw/**

---

Adding extra variables to `arguments` is a little bit tricky since `arguments` not is a real array, it does not have prototype methods such as `push()`. This workaround will work :

```
footerCallback: function() {
  var newArguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
  newArguments.push('client')
  dataTableFooterCallback.apply(this, newArguments)
}
```

In `dataTableFooterCallback()` `'client'` is now added as last param in the function call. See updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/95h3a8nw/1/**

Comment: This was a great answer. Thanks..! 
Now one more question, if I want to pass `'client'` with the arguments, what should I do?